# How to get data via springboot JPA at ApplicationScope

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have requirement to get data when the application starts and the data remains throughout the application scope as this the reference data which will be used further

Here is my bean which stores data at Application scope 
*ApplicationBean.java*

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ApplicationBean {

    @Getter
    private List<Discounts> discountList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Autowired
    private DiscountService discountService;

    @Bean
    @ApplicationScope
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public  void getDiscounts(){
    log.info("Inside Application Scope...");
        discountList=discountService.getAllDiscounts();
    }
}
```

*DiscountService.java*

```
@Service
public class DiscountService {

    @Autowired
    private DiscountRepository discountRepository;

   public List<Discounts> getAllDiscounts(){

       return discountRepository.findAll();
    }
    
}
```

Here is the Repository *DiscountRepository.java*

```
@Repository
public interface DiscountRepository extends JpaRepository<Discounts,Long> {
    @Override
    List<Discounts> findAll();

    @Override
    List<Discounts> findAllById(Iterable<Long> longs);

}
```

*Error*

```text
19:52:27.154 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
19:52:27.169 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.54]
19:52:27.295 [main] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
19:52:27.342 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
19:52:27.717 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
19:52:28.038 [main] INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
19:52:28.124 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
19:52:28.290 [main] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
19:52:28.463 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
19:52:29.170 [main] INFO  o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
19:52:29.641 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
19:52:29.657 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
19:52:29.657 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
**19:52:29.688 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDiscounts' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [com/xyz/bookingservice/config/ApplicationBean.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of void: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class void**
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.xyz.bookingservice.BookingserviceApplication.main(BookingserviceApplication.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of void: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class void
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:209)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean.setBeanFactory(ScopedProxyFactoryBean.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1826)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1791)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class void
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:660)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:358)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:206)
    ... 20 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

*I am not sure how to achieve this? Do I have to change scope of DiscountService and DiscountRepository to ApplicationScope?*

Comment: Why do you think that you must use @ApplicationScope?

Comment: Both `@Bean` and `@ApplicationScope` won't work on a `void` method and are as well pretty useless here. Spring beans are singleton by default and live throughout the application, so the default scope is enough. Instead of an event listener just use an `@PostConstruct` or better and `ApplicationListener` (the latter will run after everything has started and has been setup).

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: I wanted data to be retain till the application is live or running irrespective of request or session. Don't want to get this static data from database every time a request comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the following:

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ApplicationBean implements ApplicationRunner {

    private List<Discounts> discountList = new ArrayList<>();

    private final DiscountService discountService;
    
    public ApplicationBean(DiscountService discountService) {
      this.discountService=discountService;
    }

    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
      this.init();
    }

    private void init(){
        log.info("Inside Application Scope...");
        discountList=discountService.getAllDiscounts();
    }

    public List<Discounts> getDiscountList() {
       return Collections.unmodifableList(this.discountList);
    }
}
```

Or just use `@PostContruct`.

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ApplicationBean {

    private List<Discounts> discountList = new ArrayList<>();

    private final DiscountService discountService;
    
    public ApplicationBean(DiscountService discountService) {
      this.discountService=discountService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        log.info("Inside Application Scope...");
        discountList=discountService.getAllDiscounts();
    }

    public List<Discounts> getDiscountList() {
       return Collections.unmodifableList(this.discountList);
    }
}
```

I changed to constructor injected as that should be the preferred way, you also want to prevent the getter from returning the actual list, but rather a copy of the list.

On a final note, you might even want to reconsider this and use the second-level caching of your JPA provider to cache the results of the query. I highly doubt that you never will add a discount and now you would need to restart your whole application just to refresh that data.